# How to parse the Windows 10 Manifest.xml file inside an .XAP or a .Appx package

Tags: javascript, java, windows, wso2, windows-10-mobile

This file appears to be in a binary XML format. What is this format and how can it be parsed programmatically with JAVA?

Note: I want to access this information from outside the windows mobile environment, preferably from Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Appx and xap files are renamed zip files. You can use whichever library you usually use to decompress and read zip files to decompress the Appx file. Once you've done that the AppxManifest.xml, WMAppManifest.xml, and AppManfiest.xaml  files are plain text xml files.